# Looking for tools on Sexp expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, s-expression

I am a recent fan of s-exp expressions in Ruby. I discovered Sexpistol parser for instance.

Are you using other dedicated tools around them (schemas etc ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out Lispy: https://github.com/ryan-allen/lispy

It's no quite s-expressions, but similar in concept..

Answer (score 0):

I've been rolling my own handlers for s-expressions in Ruby, but I'm loving the relative ease with which they can be manipulated.

If you haven't seen Ruby's built-in Ripper library yet, it's worth checking out:

```
> require 'ripper'
> Ripper.sexp("1 + 1")
 => [:program, [[:binary, [:@int, "1", [1, 0]], :+, [:@int, "1", [1, 4]]]]]
```

Comment: Where can I find what `[1, 0]` or `[1, 4]` in `@int` definition is?

Comment: I'm not sure where these are documented.  I'm guessing they're token length and number of characters into the input.  They can safely be ignored.

Comment: I found fragment from "Ruby under the microscope" book, and that part of ".sexp" output is ignored there too. Thanks for your version/guess, though, looks very probable.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest lib available is [sfsexp](http://sexpr.sourceforge.net/) (the small, fast s-expression library). It is written in C with Ruby bindings that you can see in action in the [API Doc](http://sexpr.sourceforge.net/#sec4).